# Laravel API return

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with my Laravel App.
I'm listing some data from the database and I'm calling a new function to list a few more information about some game servers. I'm successfully listing all the needed info, but it's not ordered well.

It's returning like

```
{
    "result": true,
    "server": [
        {
            "id": 2512,
            "clientid": 2,
            "boxid": 23,
            "ipid": 60,
            "ips": [
                {
                    "id": 60,
                    "boxid": 23,
                    "ip": "178.63.45.131",
                    "usage": "Game Servers",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2385,
            "clientid": 2,
            "boxid": 20,
            "ipid": 53,
            "ips": [
                {
                    "id": 53,
                    "boxid": 20,
                    "ip": "185.119.89.89",
                    "usage": "Game Servers",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "query": [
        {
            "server": {
                "sv_version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio,48,2117",
                "sv_voiceenable": "1",
                "sv_wateraccelerate": "10",
                "sv_waterfriction": "1",
                "teams": [],
                "version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio"
            }
        },
        {
            "server": {
                "sv_version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio,48,1988",
                "sv_voiceenable": "0",
                "sv_wateraccelerate": "10",
                "sv_waterfriction": "1",
                "teams": [],
                "version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How I want it to return:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "server": [
        {
            "id": 2512,
            "clientid": 2,
            "boxid": 23,
            "ipid": 60,
            "ips": [
                {
                    "id": 60,
                    "boxid": 23,
                    "ip": "178.63.45.131",
                    "usage": "Game Servers",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ],
            "query": [
                {
                    "server": {
                    "sv_version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio,48,2117",
                    "sv_voiceenable": "1",
                    "sv_wateraccelerate": "10",
                    "sv_waterfriction": "1",
                    "teams": [],
                    "version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2385,
            "clientid": 2,
            "boxid": 20,
            "ipid": 53,
            "ips": [
                {
                    "id": 53,
                    "boxid": 20,
                    "ip": "185.119.89.89",
                    "usage": "Game Servers",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ],
            "query": [
                {
                    "sv_version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio,48,1988",
                "sv_voiceenable": "0",
                "sv_wateraccelerate": "10",
                "sv_waterfriction": "1",
                "teams": [],
                "version": "1.1.2.7/Stdio"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So basically it's returning all data correctly, the only problem is that it's listing separately that data, but it should be in one. This is how my code looks like:

```
public function index(){

        $user = auth()->user();
        $servers = Server::where('clientid', $user->id)
               ->with('ips')
               ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
               ->get();


        foreach ($servers as $key => $server) {
            $boxid[$key] = $server->boxid;

            $GameQ = new \GameQ\GameQ();
            $GameQ->addServer([
                'id' => 'server',
                'type' => 'cs16',
                'host' => $server->ips[0]->ip . ":" . $server->port
            ]);

            $results[$key] = $GameQ->process();
            $data[$key] = $server;
        }    



        if ($user) {
            $reposne['result'] = true;
            $reposne['server'] = $data;
            $reposne['query'] = $results;
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $reposne;
    }
```

Comment: Your 'query' structure is inserted to the root of the JSON with `$reponse['query'] = $results` instead of being a part of the `$reponse['server']` structure. During your object construction, you should probably add `$results` as part of your `$GameQ->addServer()` call.

Also, you name `$reponse` in most places but you spell it `$response` in your `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**
The main problem is when and where you put query value. Into your response, query come from this `$reposne['query'] = $results;`. When you look inside the index function, $results is created during foreach loop like this `$results[$key] = $GameQ->process();`. $results appear nowhere else into the code, so query and server value will never be mix.

**How to solve**
During the foreach loop, append the query value to the server one.

Give a try to that code:

```
public function index(){

    $user = auth()->user();
    $servers = Server::where('clientid', $user->id)
           ->with('ips')
           ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
           ->get();


    foreach ($servers as $key => $server) {
        $boxid[$key] = $server->boxid;

        $GameQ = new \GameQ\GameQ();
        $GameQ->addServer([
            'id' => 'server',
            'type' => 'cs16',
            'host' => $server->ips[0]->ip . ":" . $server->port
        ]);

        //Magic happen here
        $server['query'] = $GameQ->process();
        $data[$key] = $server;
    }    



    if ($user) {
        $reposne['result'] = true;
        $reposne['server'] = $data;//And there
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $reposne;
}
```

**Suggestion**
Actually in your code, seems like you are using user only to know if some one is authentified. If not, you don't want this code to be execute. I suggest you to stop the execution the earlier you can know the code should not be.

```
public function index(){
    if (Auth::check()) {
        ...
        //your code
        ...

        $reposne['result'] = true;
        $reposne['server'] = $data;

        return $reposne;
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    //If you prefer
    if (!Auth::check()) {return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);}

    ...
    //your code
    ...

    $reposne['result'] = true;
    $reposne['server'] = $data;

    return $reposne;
}
```

You can also use the auth middleware on you route to prevent the request to ever reach that piece of code in case the user is not logged.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes